# Does Trie Node store the character value?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, trie

I am learning Trie and get a bit confused from the description in wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

It appears in the example picture that the characters are stored in both the node and edge? What's the most common implementation of the node class? Do people usually store the character  in the node object? Or do they usually store it with the edge?

thanks!

Comment: When I used Tries, the way a character was referenced was in the parent node.  When I did it, I used an array of length 26 to represent the different characters.  For example, the word "cab" would have a child node in the 3rd slot of the parent array, which would have a child node in the 1st slot, which would have a child in the second slot.  Each node only holds a count and an array of Trie children.

Comment: so you basically use the index value in the child array to identify the char value? 1st = 'a', 2nd = 'b', etc...? Is that because you want to save the space as much as you can?

Comment: It's actually because it's the simplest way -- again, that's how I've done it, not necessarily the "best" way, but it worked well for me.  And, as mentioned in an answer below, it's as simple as `children[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characters need to at least be stored on the edge (well, as a technicality, I'm not sure whether I'd classify it as being stored on the edge, but rather on the parent).

The reasoning behind this - How will you efficiently find a string in the tree if you don't know what characters the children represents? At each level, you'll have to look through all the children:

```
for each child c
  if c.char == character we're looking for
```

instead of just: (assume `children` is a `Map` of `Character` to `Node`)

```
children.get(character we're looking for)
```

You can of course 'store' the character more compactly - if you have only lower-case characters, you can just have an array - `Node children[26]`, where you'd do look-ups like:

```
children[character we're looking for - 'a']
```

meaning `children[0]` would be the child for `'a'`, `children[1]` the child for `'b'`, etc.

Comment: This makes more sense. It probably depends on the use case. If my char set is broader than 26 chars, or if the chars that I am using is much less than 26 chars, then I may not want to use a static char[26] array on every node (because of waste of space). In that case, a Map<Character,Node> might be better?

Comment: Yes, once your character set gets a bit larger, the array approach is no longer viable. Note that a map has quite a bit of space overhead. Even if only 1/2 or 1/3 of the elements are populated, `Node[26]` is likely to still use less space than a map (and will also be faster).

Answer (score 0):

I  think an edge makes more sense when you have a 2d array or a matrix. It can be complicated to build a tree and store value in edges.

Comment: I feel like storing the char value with the node is easier to implement but not sure if there is any other disadvantage to it.